# Oracle SQL: Outer Join Not Working As Expected

Tags: oracle, join

I am joining two tables, `T_ADMSTU_PROG_ENROLL` (renamed `prog_enroll`) and `T_ADMGRAD_STUDENT` (renamed `grad`). I would expect the result to have the following columns:

```
TERM_CODE, STU_INST_UID, MAJOR_DESC, MAJOR_CIP, B_GRADUATION_TERM
```

keyed on `prog_enroll.STU_INST_UID = grad.STU_INST_UID and prog.enroll TERM_CODE = B_GRADUATION_TERM` and include all rows from both tables. I am, however, missing rows from `T_ADMGRAD_STUDENT` where the value `B_GRADUATION_TERM` is not in the `TERM_CODE`. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT prog_enroll.TERM_CODE, prog_enroll.STU_INST_UID, prog_enroll.MAJOR_DESC,prog_enroll.MAJOR_CIP, grad.B_GRADUATION_TERM FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT TERM_CODE, STU_INST_UID, LISTAGG(CIP_CODE,'+') WITHIN
GROUP(ORDER BY CIP_CODE) as MAJOR_CIP,
LISTAGG(CIP_DESCR,'+') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY CIP_CODE) as MAJOR_DESC
FROM
T_ADMSTU_PROG_ENROLL
WHERE
DEGREE_LEVEL_CODE = 'B' AND COLL_TYPE = 'MT'
GROUP BY TERM_CODE, STU_INST_UID) prog_enroll
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT STU_INST_UID, B_GRADUATION_TERM
FROM
T_ADMGRAD_STUDENT
WHERE
STUDENT_ACADEMIC_LEVEL = 'US'
)  grad
ON
grad.STU_INST_UID = prog_enroll.STU_INST_UID
AND
grad.B_GRADUATION_TERM = prog_enroll.TERM_CODE;
```

Comment: Post the database version and execution plan of the query. There are some wrong result bugs related to `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps changing your JOIN condition slightly might help if you want 
the value B_GRADUATION_TERM that doesn't match TERM_CODE without creating a Cartesian join :

**From:**

```
grad.B_GRADUATION_TERM = prog_enroll.TERM_CODE;
```

**To:**

```
 (grad.B_GRADUATION_TERM = prog_enroll.TERM_CODE or grad.B_GRADUATION_TERM is NULL);
```

**As shown completely here:**

```
SELECT prog_enroll.TERM_CODE, prog_enroll.STU_INST_UID, prog_enroll.MAJOR_DESC,prog_enroll.MAJOR_CIP, grad.B_GRADUATION_TERM FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT TERM_CODE, STU_INST_UID, LISTAGG(CIP_CODE,'+') WITHIN
GROUP(ORDER BY CIP_CODE) as MAJOR_CIP,
LISTAGG(CIP_DESCR,'+') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY CIP_CODE) as MAJOR_DESC
FROM
T_ADMSTU_PROG_ENROLL
WHERE
DEGREE_LEVEL_CODE = 'B' AND COLL_TYPE = 'MT'
GROUP BY TERM_CODE, STU_INST_UID) prog_enroll
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT STU_INST_UID, B_GRADUATION_TERM
FROM
T_ADMGRAD_STUDENT
WHERE
STUDENT_ACADEMIC_LEVEL = 'US'
)  grad
ON
grad.STU_INST_UID = prog_enroll.STU_INST_UID
AND
(grad.B_GRADUATION_TERM = prog_enroll.TERM_CODE or grad.B_GRADUATION_TERM is NULL);
```